# Why does gmail fail to apply the filters for imported emails?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, email-forwarding

I forward my emails from
(1) IEEE using an alias (@ieee.org)
(2) AOL as imported via POP (@aol.com)

I use the filters to label incoming email.

I noticed that the filters I set up in gmail only work with the emails that were addressed as @gmail.com. Cases (1) and (2) above do not activate the labeling filters as they arrive.

I tried modifying the filters to include the to: field for cases (1) and (2), but they did not work neither.

Is there a way to make filters work with cases (1) and (2) above? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome, Amante. It might just be a mismatch in the filters. E.g. try opening such an email and use the "Filter messages like this" command in the message's menu. Or open one of your filters and ask it to Search for matching messages. I'd expect forwarded email to get filtered like other incoming messages; possibly not the POP server access.

Comment: I've already tried your suggestions above. It works for emails already received in the inbox. But what I want is that incoming emails that are either forwarded or imported as in cases (1) and (2) are labeled according to the filters using the address in the to: field of the filter.

Comment: The alias case is more surprising -- my rule on `from:(anti-spam@acm.org) to:(myname@acm.org) subject:("ACM Detected Potential Junk Mail")` works, or used to work. Gmail rules are rough around the edges, e.g. creating a rule on `in:spam from:"Fidelity"` warns about rules that depend on the messages already having a label, but it works. Gmail docs used to be more comprehensive. You might ask the community forum: https://support.google.com/mail/community?hl=en

Comment: @franta Please don't remove [tag:gmail] from questions about Gmail. Also avoid to include meta tags like [tag:migrate-data].

Comment: @Rubén - Please, navigate me to the rules of labels, where they are defined: So I could be sure next time, what labels are legitimate. Thanks.

Comment: Have you already read [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)?

Answer (score -1):

Similar issue is with messages (SMSes) imported to gMail via an Android app from my phone: The import process labels my SMSes by the "lable:sms"... But it is the app itself (I assume), not the gMail mailer daemon-labeller.

So in general:

- Whichever import does add messages to the gMail, can apply any label, i.e. even the label:inbox,
- but it does not really fire-up the filtering process on the particular message.

I just assume, that the "new-email daemon" is different than the particular "import daemon" / or the "new-mail waiting daemon", of the gMail incoming-mail-client, is not used for the imported messages. The "new-mail" "apply-filters" process is not activated, not applied on the side-coming messages.

The massages coming through the real mail-channel seem to be treated as virgin messages, and the gMail-filtering (labeling) seems applied only for these virgin-emails.